# java regex Pattern.compile multiple characters

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a java pattern to identify all special characters except `"0123456789"` or `"("` or `")"` or `"|"` or `"-"` or `" "`.

Can somebody help me to get an answer?

I wanted to use `Pattern.compile` and `pattern.matcher` to find out this.

Comment: Did you make any attempt to do this yourself? The java.util.regex.Pattern javadoc seems to be pretty clear on how to use the metacharacters.

Comment: You should get some pointers from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html

Comment: `(?:[all special characters](?<![\d()| -]))+` is one way. The ways this can be expressed is endless..

Comment: Try [^()|\- a-zA-Z0-9]

Comment: Thanks... But I have got another combination [^0-9\\s\\|\\(\\)\\-]

Comment: @ShellFish: **Every** regex question is a possible duplicate of that one; that's why they closed it. ;)

Comment: No, only incredibly basic ones are. Posts that don't show effort and are solvable with minimal effort and a single read through that guide are dupes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all characters separately you can use this pattern-

```
/[^ 0123456789()|\-]/g
```

Or if you want to find blocks of consecutive characters, you should use this-

```
/[^ 0123456789()|\-]+/g
```

This will identify all characters except those inside `[^(*this part*)]`

By the way, if you want to research further about regex pattern http://regexr.com/ will be very helpful. There are quick references and tutorials to help you learn the basics of regex quickly.

Comment: You need to escape that hyphen (`\-`) or move it to the last position: `[^0123456789()| -]`.  Both Java and RegExr will treat `[|- ]` as a range, and throw an exception because the end points are listed in the wrong order.  But I don't think we have enough information to answer this question yet.  For example, what does the author mean by "special characters"?